# Stored procedure is not concurrent

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, deadlock

I want this stored procedure to work concurrently, but as I see in PgAdmin it doesn't. One process is blocked by another one (waits him to finish). Seems to me, update query has no problems with being running concurrently. So this is all about INSERT, am I right? I tried to set ROW SHARE EXCLUSIVE LOCK on update query, but I've reached deadlock.

```
    UPDATE product p SET category_id = m.internal_category_id, category_from=m.cat_prior FROM main_table m
    WHERE  p.mpn=m.mpn AND
    p.vendor_id = m.internal_vendor_id  AND
    m.new_prod=false and
    m.internal_category_id IS NOT NULL AND
    (category_from is null or category_from<=m.cat_prior);

    INSERT INTO product(vendor_id, category_id, mpn, name, category_from)
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(m.mpn, m.internal_vendor_id) m.internal_vendor_id, m.internal_category_id, m.mpn, m.prod_name, m.cat_prior
    FROM main_table m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product ON product.mpn=m.mpn AND product.vendor_id=m.internal_vendor_id
    WHERE m.new_prod='1' AND m.internal_vendor_id IS NOT NULL
    AND product.mpn IS NULL;

    UPDATE main_table m SET internal_product_id = p.id
    FROM product p
    WHERE p.mpn=m.mpn AND p.vendor_id = m.internal_vendor_id ;

    UPDATE vendor SET has_products = true FROM (SELECT DISTINCT v.id as id FROM vendor v INNER JOIN product p ON p.vendor_id = v.id) AS r WHERE vendor.id = r.id;
    UPDATE vendor SET has_products = false FROM (SELECT DISTINCT v.id as id FROM vendor v LEFT JOIN product p ON p.vendor_id = v.id WHERE p.vendor_id IS NULL) AS r WHERE vendor.id = r.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Seems to me, update query has no problems with being running
 concurrently. So this is all about INSERT, am I right?*

Both can be problematic but UPDATE tends to be more problematic with regard to interlocking.

When an UPDATE modifies a row and another UPDATE tries to modify the same row, the second is put to wait until the first transaction commits or rolls back.

On the other hand, when two INSERTs hit the same table, the second one is made to wait only if there's a unique index on the table and both statements are trying to insert the same indexed value. Which is unusual because that would lead to an index violation error unless the first transaction aborts.

Just by looking at a piece of code, it's hard to know whether concurrent calls will hit the same rows or not, it depends on the data. However in your case it's a bit suspicious that your first UPDATE doesn't seem to take any parameter.